# Excel Lock File - Why can i copy it, but not open it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-permissions, lock

If i have an Excel file `SomeFile.xlsx` open, a file is created `~SomeFile.xlsx` that contains the name of the user who has opened/locked the Excel file. I can't directly open the file in Notepad, but I can copy it and then open the copy.

If the file can be copied then obviously it **can** be opened for read access. So why can't I just open it in Notepad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of windows' [File Locking mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking):

> File locking is a mechanism that restricts access to a computer file
>   by allowing only one user or process to access it in a specific time.
>   Systems implement locking to prevent the classic interceding update
>   scenario, which is a typical example of race condition, by enforcing
>   the serialization of update processes to any given file

Normally, you should not be able even see this hidden file (unless you change the default settings).
You can copy the locked file, which stay hidden but can now be open for write / read access.

Comment: Cheer duDE! So does that mean there's a low level API that will let me read the file without copying it first?

Comment: Sure, the Win32API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-unlockfile

Comment: So is that the method Windows Explorer uses when it copies a file? UnlockFile > Read > Write > (Relock?).

Comment: With high probability that is it ;)